# Как создать возможность в функции PHP принимать переменное количество параметров?

Tags: php

Есть функция вида:

```
function android($a, $b, $c, $d) 
{ .... какой-то код .....
```

Примеры вызовов:

```
android('string', 'string2');
android('string', 'string2', 'string3');
android('string', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4');
```

Как видно, функция вызывается с переменным числом параметров. Как реализовать эту функцию так, чтобы она могла принимать переменное число входных параметров, в зависимости от их количества, т.е. когда-то 2 параметра, когда-то - 3 и т.д. И чтобы при этом не было ошибок. Спасибо

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте многоточие ... чтобы определить, что функция использует переменное кол-во параметров. Внутри функции аргументы будут представлены в виде массива.

Пример:

```
function doSomething(...$params): void
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        if (is_integer($param)) {
            $params[$key] *= 2;
        }
    }

    var_dump($params);
}

$var1 = 100;
$var2 = 3.14;

doSomething($var1, $var2, 'a', []);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Meow, спасибо за ответ. Но я тут немного не улавливаю суть. Конструкция типа (...$params) выглядит так, что у нас в параметрах значится только одна переменная $params. Т.е. если, если мы передадим 3 параметра, то как будет называться переменная для каждого из них?

Comment: @SerG это будет массив

Answer (score 0):

```
public function doit($params = [])
{
 // lorem
}
```

А так не проще, вместо троеточий и лишних слов ? Передал сколько нужно параметров и обработал по надобности..иль я чего то не понял ?